# how to make jquery not blur the edges

Tags: jquery, html, web

I have given this to blur an image but i also blurs the edges of the pictures which makes it weird for a website

```
$(function() {
    $({blurRadius: 0}).animate({blurRadius: 2}, {
        duration: 1500,
        easing: 'swing', // or "linear"
                         // use jQuery UI or Easing plugin for more options
        step: function() {
            console.log(this.blurRadius);
            $('.item').css({
                "-webkit-filter": "blur("+this.blurRadius+"px)",
                "filter": "blur("+this.blurRadius+"px)"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `.item` with additional `div` with `overflow: hidden`. Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/journeyman/b7ekzgh0/).

**Short details:**

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    filter: blur(10px);
}

div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```